# Ontario HST rebate: When in December 2010 will we receive our HST cheque?

Tags: canada, hst, ontario, rebate

***Does anybody know when in December 2010 we will be receiving our HST cheques?***

Answer (score 4):

The first payment in June 2010 was direct deposited on the 10th of month.  December's payment will most likely be around the same date.

Comment: Yup, it was today the 10th.

Answer (score 3):

Eligibility is based on your residency on November 30, 2010, so I wouldn't expect it until mid-month at the earliest.

See http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/index.html